# How can I use Powershell to extract mail headers from .msg file?

Tags: email, powershell

I'm trying to write a script that reads the mail headers from a directory full of .msg files so I can later parse them via regex. I tried `$MSG = Get-Content .\message.msg`, which could work, but it's a pretty dirty output. Has anyone tried this? I can't seem to find a working example online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options depending on your environment. If you are on a computer with Outlook installed you can easily do this with an Outlook com object. The problem is that the headers are not exposed by default so you have to [dig for them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868350.aspx).

```
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$msg = $ol.CreateItemFromTemplate("SOME\PATH\TO\A\MSG\FILE.msg")
$headers = $msg.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
$headers
```

At this point you have a text block with all of the header information in it. If you want a specific header you will need to write a regex to extract it.

You could also write a class that reads the raw content based on [the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx). Or read in the raw content with powershell and write a regex to attempt to extract it.